# What is the meaning of a "trip angle" in a level sensor?

Tags: sensors, terminology

What does trip angle mean in the context of [slope  / level sensors / inclinometers](http://www.pqcontrols.com/m410.php)?

Comment: You might want to expand your question to include what sort of application or problem you're trying to solve. Right now it sounds almost like a sensitivity? I.e. the sensor won't register a change in inclination/angle until it reaches the 'trip angle'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link that you provided, it would seem that trip angle is a preset angle at which the sensor will "trip" or "switch on". The results of this can depend on purpose of the tilt meter. It can be wired to sound an alarm, turn on a light, etc.

From this [spec sheet](http://www.spectronsensors.com/appsheets/SAN-218-2109.pdf) on another tile switch, the trip angle can be adjustable.  The spec sheet also gives an example circuit.

Another [sensor on the site](http://www.pqcontrols.com/m420.php) that you linked gives possible uses.